# Fuzzy matching duplicates in postgresql and move the duplicates to a new table

Tags: sql, postgresql, similarity

I have a User table, that has the following fields
 `id, first_name, last_name, street_address, city, state, zip-code, firm, user_identifier, created_at, update_at`.
This table that has a lot of duplicates.

I would like to fuzzy match them by `first_name, last_name and street_address`.

**Here is what I have done**

I created a new table with the following fields

```
CREATE TABLE dupes(
   id  bigint NOT NULL,
   first_name    TEXT,
   last_name      TEXT,
   street_address        CHAR(50),
   searched_name TEXT,
   searched_user_id bigint
);
```

Next I have this func that it supposed to loop through the fields and insert into new table (`dupes`) where the similarity is above ```.75

```
DO 
$$
DECLARE 
    rec record;
    full_name varchar;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN 
    SELECT id, first_name ||' '||last_name ||' '||street_address full_name 
    FROM users

    LOOP
        INSERT INTO dupes(id,first_name,last_name, street_address,searched_name, searched_user_id)
        SELECT id,first_name,last_name, street_address,rec.full_name,rec.id 
        FROM users
        WHERE similarity(first_name ||' '||last_name||' '||street_address, rec.full_name) > .75
        and  id<>rec.id;
    END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Unfortunately, I am getting more copies of every row returned.

I'm pretty new at this. Can anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not require procedural programming. (Doing it set based might even save you from too many duplicate duplicates… ;-) )

For a start:

```
WITH
Matching (id, first_name, last_name, street_address, searched_name, searched_user_id) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    l.id
    , l.first_name
    , l.last_name
    , l.street_address
    , r.first_name || ' ' || r.last_name
    , r.id
  FROM Users l
  JOIN Users r
    ON SIMILARITY(l.first_name || ' ' || l.last_name || ' ' || l.street_address,
                  r.first_name || ' ' || r.last_name || ' ' || r.street_address) > .50
       AND l.id < r.id
)
-- SELECT * FROM Matching
INSERT INTO Dupes (id, first_name, last_name, street_address, searched_name, searched_user_id)
  (SELECT id, first_name, last_name, street_address, searched_name, searched_user_id FROM Matching)
;
```

(To illustrate the match between three records without too much letter pushing, the threshold has been adjusted…)

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d1e7f/2)

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: that helped. Thank you so much. I just had to to make ```id```  UNIQUE,  add  `ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING` at insert so I don't get duplicates.

Comment: @MarianaLungu: Please make sure this has the intended effect on your real data / does facilitate your ensuing process(ing). (The `DISTINCT` does already prevent duplicates at the record level - not regarding the **id** alone, though. - So, the returned set is unique for the combination of **id** and **searched_user_id**. - Just thinking of _transitive closure_ and _minimal set_…)